# Дублирование предлога в приложении

Tags: синтаксис, приложение

**К** тебе, дураку, никто не придёт.

**К** тебе, **к** дураку, никто не придёт.

Есть ли в литературе какие-нибудь внятные рекомендации относительно дублирования предлога в обособленном приложении?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102483/discussion-on-question-by------).

Comment: Рекомендации проблематично найти. Но люди используют первый вариант, так как повторение избыточно, предлог само собой разумеется и его не сильно орфоэпически удобно повторять. (Для ответа 
 это коротковато.)

Answer (score 1):

К стилистическим фигурам речи, усиливающим воздействие благодаря определённым синтаксическим построениям, но **не привносящим нового содержания**, могут быть причислены и примеры звуковых и лексических анафор.

*Я прямо к тебе, к первому; Ещё шесть дней ― и к тебе, к твоим северным серым глазам.*

Часто анафора соединяется с другой риторической фигурой — градацией, которая усиливает её ритмически.

*Только как же мне к тебе, к такому, примениться?*

Весьма распространена и трёхчленная градация.

*В заботе сладостно-туманной; 
Не час, не день, не год уйдет; 
Я к тебе обращаю мою речь, к тебе, к человеку.*

(О видах лексических повторов можно прочитать здесь: https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/320)